# Python Conv Neural Network Inference function problems

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

I have never programmed in Python before and I have to write an inference function for a class.  The bulk of the code was written for the students and we just have to make the inference function.  I found some examples online, but we have to use different layers than what the examples online were using.  I'm getting confused on shaping, but I'm not too sure about any of the code.

Here is what I have:

```
    import tensorflow as tf

    def _variable_with_weight_decay(name, shape, wd):
      with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        var = tf.get_variable(name, shape, 
                    initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
      if wd is not None:
        weight_decay = tf.multiply(tf.nn.l2_loss(var), wd, 
    name='weight_loss')
        tf.add_to_collection('losses', weight_decay)
      return var

    def inference(X,phase=False,dropout_rate=0.8,n_classes=10,weight_decay=1e-4):
# logits should be of dimension (batch_size, n_classes)
# X is tensor with dimension (NONE, 32, 32,3)

# conv layer 1
batchSize = tf.shape(X)[0] # is this batch_size?

with tf.variable_scope('conv1') as scope:
    kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[5, 5, 3, 64], wd=weight_decay)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(X, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    biases = tf.get_variable('biases', [64], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    pre_activation = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(pre_activation, name=scope.name)
    pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool1')
# Batch Normalization
#Batch variables
epsilon = 1e-3
batch_mean1, batch_var1 = tf.nn.moments(pool1,[0])
scale1 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([64]))
beta1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([64]))
batch1 = tf.nn.batch_normalization(pool1,batch_mean1,batch_var1,scale1,beta1,epsilon)
    with tf.variable_scope('conv2') as scope:

    kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[5, 5, 64, 64], wd=weight_decay)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(batch1, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    biases = tf.get_variable('biases', [64], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    pre_activation = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
    conv2 = tf.nn.relu(pre_activation, name=scope.name)
    pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv2, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool1')

#Batch Normalization 2
#Batch variables
batch_mean2, batch_var2 = tf.nn.moments(pool2,[0])
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
scale2 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([64]))
beta2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([64]))
batch2 = tf.nn.batch_normalization(pool2,batch_mean2,batch_var2,scale2,beta2,epsilon)
#dropout 2
drop2 = tf.nn.dropout(batch2, keep_prob)
    with tf.variable_scope('local1') as scope:
    reshape = tf.reshape(drop2, [batchSize, -1])
    #dim = reshape.get_shape()[1].value
    dim = reshape[-1].value
    weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[dim, 384], wd=0.004)
    biases = tf.get_variable('biases', [384], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
    local1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshape, weights) + biases, name=scope.name)
    # #_activation_summary(local1)
    # # local2
with tf.variable_scope('local2') as scope:
    weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[384, 192], wd=0.004)
    biases = tf.get_variable('biases', [192], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
    local2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(local1, weights) + biases, name=scope.name)



with tf.variable_scope('softmax_linear') as scope:
    weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', [192, n_classes], wd=None)
    biases = tf.get_variable('biases', [n_classes], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
    logits = tf.add(tf.matmul(local2, weights), biases, name=scope.name)



return logits
```

I'm supposed to have 4 convolutional layers, but that got way too confusing for me.  Now this messes up.  It keeps saying the rank is 1 and 0 or something.  How do I reshape to make it (batch_size, n_samples)?  And I know the indentation is off, but that was just how I pasted it in this, not in my actual code.

Thanks

EDIT--------------------------------------------------------

ok, so I fixed some of this, but now what is giving me a problem is the line

```
    dim = reshape.get_shape()[1].value
```

my batch size is 32, until the end when it changes to 16.  Like if there are 336 total, there would be 10 full batches of 32 and 1 batch of 16.  The line above gives the error, "Shape of new variable must be fully defined, but instead was (?,256)."

Here is my entire new code.  I went ahead and tried to do 4 convolution layers.

```
    import tensorflow as tf

    def _variable_with_weight_decay(name, shape, wd):
      with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        var = tf.get_variable(name, shape, initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
      if wd is not None:
        weight_decay = tf.multiply(tf.nn.l2_loss(var), wd, name='weight_loss')
        tf.add_to_collection('losses', weight_decay)
      return var  

    def inference(X,phase=False,dropout_rate=0.8,n_classes=10,weight_decay=1e-4):
# logits should be of dimension (batch_size, n_classes)


# conv layer 1
#batchSize = tf.shape(X)[0]
batchSize = X.get_shape().as_list()[0]
if batchSize is None:
    batchSize = 32

with tf.variable_scope('conv1') as scope:
    kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[5, 5, 3, 64], wd=weight_decay)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(X, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    biases = tf.get_variable('biases', [64], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    pre_activation = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(pre_activation, name=scope.name)
    #_activation_summary(conv1)

# pool1
pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool1')
# Batch Normalization
#Batch variables
epsilon = 1e-3
batch_mean1, batch_var1 = tf.nn.moments(pool1,[0])
scale1 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([64]))
beta1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([64]))
batch1 = tf.nn.batch_normalization(pool1,batch_mean1,batch_var1,scale1,beta1,epsilon)
#dropout 1
#keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[batchSize,32,32,3])
#drop1 = tf.nn.dropout(batch1, keep_prob)

#conv layer 2

with tf.variable_scope('conv2') as scope:

    kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[5, 5, 64, 128], wd=weight_decay)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(batch1, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    biases = tf.get_variable('biases', [128], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    pre_activation = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
    conv2 = tf.nn.relu(pre_activation, name=scope.name)
    #_activation_summary(conv2)



#pool 2
pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv2, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool1')

#Batch Normalization 2
#Batch variables
batch_mean2, batch_var2 = tf.nn.moments(pool2,[0])
scale2 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([128]))
beta2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([128]))
batch2 = tf.nn.batch_normalization(pool2,batch_mean2,batch_var2,scale2,beta2,epsilon)
#dropout 2
#drop2 = tf.nn.dropout(batch2, keep_prob)

#conv layer 3

with tf.variable_scope('conv3') as scope:
    kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[5, 5, 128, 256], wd=weight_decay)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(batch2, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    biases = tf.get_variable('biases', [256], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    pre_activation = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
    conv3 = tf.nn.relu(pre_activation, name=scope.name)
    #_activation_summary(conv3)


#pool 3
pool3 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv3, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool3')
#Batch Normalization 3
#Batch variables
batch_mean3, batch_var3 = tf.nn.moments(pool3,[0])
scale3 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([256]))
beta3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([256]))
batch3 = tf.nn.batch_normalization(pool3,batch_mean3,batch_var3,scale3,beta3,epsilon)
#dropout 3
#drop3 = tf.nn.dropout(batch3, keep_prob)

# conv layer 3

with tf.variable_scope('conv4') as scope:
    kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[5, 5, 256, 256], wd=weight_decay)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(batch3, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    biases = tf.get_variable('biases', [256], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    pre_activation = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
    conv4 = tf.nn.relu(pre_activation, name=scope.name)
    #_activation_summary(conv4)


#pool 4
pool4 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv4, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool4')
#Batch Normalization 4
#Batch variables
batch_mean4, batch_var4 = tf.nn.moments(pool4,[0])
scale4 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([256]))
beta4 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([256]))
batch4 = tf.nn.batch_normalization(pool4,batch_mean4,batch_var4,scale4,beta4,epsilon)
#dropout 4
#drop4 = tf.nn.dropout(batch4, keep_prob)


# local layer

with tf.variable_scope('local1') as scope:
    reshape = tf.reshape(batch4, [batchSize, -1])
    dim = reshape.get_shape()[1].value
    #dim = batchSize*32
    weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[dim, 256], wd=0.004)
    biases = tf.get_variable('biases', [256], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
    local1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshape, weights) + biases, name=scope.name)
    # #_activation_summary(local1)
    # # local2
with tf.variable_scope('local2') as scope:
    weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[256, batchSize], wd=0.004)
    biases = tf.get_variable('biases', [batchSize], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
    local2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(local1, weights) + biases, name=scope.name)
    # #_activation_summary(local2)


with tf.variable_scope('softmax_linear') as scope:
    #reshape = tf.reshape(batch4, [batchSize, n_classes])
    weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', [batchSize, n_classes], wd=None)
    biases = tf.get_variable('biases', [n_classes], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
    logits = tf.add(tf.matmul(local2, weights), biases, name=scope.name)
    #_activation_summary(logits)


return logits
```